# Vote system is not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vote, review

I have an application where you can write articles, and other users can vote on the articles if they like it. But, unfortunately, the vote system is not working fine. After an article receives the first vote, other users are unable to vote on the same article, here is my code:

Review Model

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
  validates_uniqueness_of :article_id, scope: :user_id
end
```

Article controller

```
def upreview
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.reviews.create
  redirect_to(:back)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is happening because `:user_id` is `nil`. In other words, the validations are working correctly, and you're only allowed to create a single `Review` per article with a `:user_id` of `nil`.

Perhaps you could do something like: `@article.reviews.create(user: current_user)`.  This would set the `:user_id` attribute.

Comment: Thanks very much, the problem is exactly it, the user_id is nil, but when I put this code @article.reviews.create(user: current_user) I get the error "Undefined Method 'reviews'", how can I fix it? Thanks again! I am trying to solve it for hours

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake, I forgot to change a thing I had made before! Thanks very much!!